# What are the default values for @QueryParam when @DefaultValue is not specified?

Tags: java, rest, javax.ws.rs, query-string

For example, having the following Java rest definition:

```
@GET
@Path("/something")
public String somthing(
    @QueryParam("valString") String valString,
    @QueryParam("valInt") int valInt,
    @QueryParam("valBool") boolean valBool
) {
  ...
}
```

And invocation:

```
curl -X GET 127.0.0.1/something
```

**What will the parameters values be if not specified in the invocation? (valString=?, valInt=?, valBool=?)**

Comment: Take a look here [https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)

Comment: @Valijon - You're saying that the REST default values are similar to Java's default class members?

Comment: they aren't similar, they are the same thing, since this is an implementation issue. REST does not mandate "default values" for parameters since it's not a specification.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

### Short answer

The parameter values will be:

- `valString`: `null`
- `valInt`: `0`
- `valBool`: `false`

### A bit longer answer

Quoting the [Java EE 7 tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/index.html) about [extracting request parameters](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jaxrs002.htm#sthref1537):

> If `@DefaultValue` is not used in conjunction with `@QueryParam`, and
>   the query parameter is not present in the request, the value will be
>   an empty collection for `List`, `Set`, or `SortedSet`; `null` for
>   other object types; and the default for primitive types.

The default values for primitive types are described in the [Java Tutorials](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html) from Oracle:

```java
 Primitive       Default Value
-------------------------------
 byte            0
 short           0
 int             0
 long            0L
 float           0.0f
 double          0.0d
 char            '\u0000'
 boolean         false
```

As you already know, this behavior can be changed by using the [`@DefaultValue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/DefaultValue.html) annotation as following:

```java
@GET
@Path("/foo")
public String myMethod(@DefaultValue("foo") @QueryParam("valString") String valString,
                       @DefaultValue("1") @QueryParam("valInt") int valInt,
                       @DefaultValue("true") @QueryParam("valBool") boolean valBool) {
    ....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

the values will be `null`, `0`, `false`, i.e. the default values for non-initialized variables of those types. If the client does not put the parameters in the URL and the service does not specify default values, what the service will get are Java default values for non-initialized variables.

Comment: On what do you base your answer?

Comment: on logic, experience and https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19798-01/821-1841/gipyw/index.html (in reverse order)